# Linear map is injective iff image of a linearly independent subset is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I've been trying to prove the following: Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces over a field $\mathbb{K}$. Let $\{v_{1},\dots, v_{n}\}\subseteq V$ be a linearly independent subset and $n\in\mathbb{N}$. A linear map $\Phi: V\rightarrow W$ is injective iff $\{\Phi(v_{1}),\dots, \Phi(v_{n})\}\subseteq W$ is linearly independent.

The first part of the proof was straightforward:

$(\Rightarrow)$ Let $\Phi$ be injective. Let $\lambda_{1},\dots,\lambda_{n}\in\mathbb{K}$, such that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}\Phi(v_{i})=0$. From another corollary I know this is equivalent to $\Phi\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}v_{i}\right)=0$. Because $\Phi(0)=0$ we then get
\begin{align*}\tag{I}
\Phi\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}v_{i}\right)=\Phi(0).
\end{align*}
Because $\Phi$ is injective, we have
\begin{align*}\tag{II}
\Phi(a)=\Phi(b)\Longrightarrow a=b
\end{align*}
for all $a,b\in V$. Applying this to (I) gives $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}v_{i}=0$. Because $v_{1},\dots, v_{n}$ are linearly independent, we then conclude $\lambda_{1}=\cdots=\lambda_{n}=0$ and therefore $\{\Phi(v_{1}),\dots,\Phi(v_{n})\}$ are linearly independent.

The second part, however...

$(\Leftarrow)$ Let $\{\Phi(v_{1}),\dots, \Phi(v_{n})\}\subseteq W$ be linearly independent. Well, that's about as far I got. I see two possibilities for this proof: I can either try show that (II) holds for all $u, v\in V$ or I could try to show that $\ker\Phi =\{0\}$, which would also imply that $\Phi$ is injective. However, I have no idea how to do that. How could I proove there is no $w\in V$ with $w\in\ker\Phi$? Also I don't see any useful relation between arbitrary vectors $u,v\in V$ to prove (II). Is my theorem wrong or did I miss anything? If $\{v_{1},\dots, v_{n}\}$ would be a spanning set of $V$ (which would make it a basis of $V$) things would be different. Any ideas?

Comment: My previous answer is just dumb, so ignore it. But I don't think the original statement is true? Take $n=1$ Then there can be some nonzero linear map give independent set but they are not injective. You need more condition. Like is $n$ the dimension of spaces or what

Comment: Indeed, consider the projection of $\mathbb{R}^3$ onto the $xy$-plane. The basis vectors $x,y$ themselves are linearly independent, and remain so after applying the projection, but the projection is not injective.

Comment: Perhaps there is a "for all $n$, $V$" missing...?